# Find if a textbox is disabled or not using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I need to find if a textbox is disabled or enabled using Jquery.

Answer (score 176, accepted):

`.prop('disabled')` will return a Boolean:

```
var isDisabled = $('textbox').prop('disabled');
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/unhjM/

Comment: For some reason this does not work on my application even though in the fiddle it works perfectly. When I run it firebug says .prop is not a function! Is it something related to the version of jquery? Anyways, .is(':disabled') seems to work fine. 
Thanks. 

Thanks.

Comment: @MohammedJoraid - [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) was introduced in jQuery 1.6 (see the docs). If you're using an earlier version of jQuery, use [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) instead.

Comment: @ChamanSaini you are misleading.
The format $('input') is intended to select a "control of type" input, while $('#input') will match an element with the id "input" regardless of it's type.

Answer (score 84):

You can find if the textbox is disabled using `is` method by passing `:disabled` selector to it. Try this.

```
if($('textbox').is(':disabled')){
     //textbox is disabled
}
```

Answer (score 15):

You can use [`$(":disabled")`](https://api.jquery.com/disabled-selector/) to select all disabled items in the current context.

To determine whether a single item is disabled you can use [`$("#textbox1").is(":disabled")`](https://api.jquery.com/is/).

Answer (score 6):

You can check if a element is disabled or not with this:

```
if($("#slcCausaRechazo").prop('disabled') == false)
{
//your code to realice 
}
```

Comment: With boolean comparison there is no need to test against `true` or `false`. Simply use `if (expr)` or `if (! expr)`, respectively.

Comment: You are right
if($("#slcCausaRechazo").prop('disabled') )
{
//your code to realice if is disabled
}

Answer (score 5):

```
 if($("element_selector").attr('disabled') || $("element_selector").prop('disabled'))
 {

    // code when element is disabled

  }
```